# Can't find Excel file in embedded resource

Tags: c#, resources, manifest, .net-assembly

I would like my winforms users to download a excel template that they should then fill in.
I've added a Excel file as a resource to my project resources, but I ca't seem to read the file to be able to save it again.

```
 var test = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
//One of the entries in test = MyProject.Properties.Resources.resources

 Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 Stream fileStream1 = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Properties.Resources.resources.ExcelTemplate.xlsx");

int len = fileStream1.Length; //Give error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[image]

(The file does not have to be in the Resouces, it can be a normal file as well, but that I can't get working as well)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something other than copy the file. I am guessing you may have to use Microsoft interop or some other library. Below simply copies the file to destination.

Also your line below
You say the excel file is a template and excel template extensions are `xltx` not `xlsx`:

```
Stream fileStream1 = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Properties.Resources.resources.ExcelTemplate.xlsx");
```

I am not sure if you have to reference it that way. But make sure you are getting the file, I am guessing you are not hence the error. Look at how my line is structured. `ExcelAsResource` is the project name.

Hope this helps.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream s = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("ExcelAsResource.Resources.TestEmbeddedExcel.xlsx");
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop\cs\TestCopy.xlsx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
s.CopyTo(fs);
fs.Close();
s.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I do believe my reference to the file is not there.  Not sure why. Your code gives the same error.  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at line "s.CopyTo(fs);"

Comment: Again that sounds like the file is not there. I would have to check your updated line: `Stream fileStream1 = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Properties.Resources.resources.ExcelTemplate.xlsx");` this line is obviously not returning your file,and I would double check the path. It doesn't look right to me.

Comment: It will depend on how you may have structured your file, but `Resources` are not under the `Properties` portion when you add the excel resource as you show, It would be under `projectName.Resources.FileName`.I am guessing the Properties qualifier is looking for the file in the wrong place.

Comment: Also... your picture shows that the excel file is a Template... if it IS a template file then even if the path is correct it will fail because templates have the extension `xltx`... you have `xlsx`